# angular2 TS2322 Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<string>' when given a string

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular 2, I have a service that handles my API calls.  In the service, I have a handleError function that returns a `Promise<string>` for the error message.  I'm trying to add some functionality to the handleError that will redirect the page afterwards to the login screen if there are credential errors.  When I do that, TypeScript throws a TS2322 error even though I'm returning the same Promise and then trying to do some chains off of it.

> error TS2322: Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type
>   'Promise<string>'.  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
private handleError(error: Error): Promise<string> {
    let message = "Something went wrong loading data from the API.";
    if (error.response.status === 0) {
      message = "Unable to contact server.  Please file a bug report.";
    }
    if (error.message) {
      message = "API Service Error retrieving page: " + error.message;
    }
    this.alerts.error(message);
    if (error.response.status === 403) {
      if (error.message.indexOf("Authentication credentials") !== -1) {
          return Promise.reject<string>(message)  // this line errs with TS2322
          .then(() => this.appState.refresh())
          .then(() => this.redirects.login())
          .then(() => this.alerts.warning("Redirected to login because no credentials found."));
      } else {
          this.redirects.index();
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject<string>(message);
}
```

Comment: None of your `then()` callbacks will ever run, because your promise is rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      return Promise.reject<string>(message)  // this line errs with TS2322
      .then(() => this.appState.refresh())
      .then(() => this.redirects.login())
      .then(() => this.alerts.warning("Redirected to login because no credentials found."));
```

Typescript is yelling at you because `appState.refresh`, `redirects.login`, or `alerts.warning` returns a void value. To chain it correctly, set a variable with the chains, then return the variable:

```
    let result = Promise.reject<string>(message);

      result.then(() => this.appState.refresh())
            .then(() => this.redirects.login())
            .then(() => this.alerts.warning("Redirected to login because no credentials found."));

    return result;
```

It's worth mentioning also that none of the `then`s will be called because your Promise rejected.

Comment: How do I indicate there's an error (Promise.reject()) and then have other actions happen?

Comment: You could change the first `then` into a `catch`, or you could just call `this.appState.refresh()` directly with the chain afterwards, since they don't require a value from the original `Promise.reject`.